# Get value of Oracle OUT parameter from a stored procedure call using Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, dapper, odac

Edit: Using the `Execute` method instead of the `Query`/`QueryMultiple` methods, my `OUT_SUCCESS` parameter now has an `AttachedParam` with with an `OracleParameter` that has the returned value. So this would work if, for instance, I *only* needed to retrieve non-cursors parameters. Then I could use `Execute` for procedures with all non-cursor output parameters and `Query`/`QueryMultiple` for procedures with *only* cursor output parameters. But what if I need to call a stored procedure that has *both* cursor and non-cursor output parameters, as is often the case?

Using `Dapper.NET` and the [`OracleDynamicParameters` class](https://gist.github.com/vijaysg/3096151) I have successfully returned and mapped multiple `IN OUT` `REF CURSOR`s, but I cannot get the value a single `OUT` parameter.

For instance, I am trying to call a stored procedure with the following spec:

```
PROCEDURE DO_SOMETHING (
    OUT_SUCCESS    OUT VARCHAR2
)
```

for which I have created a corresponding C# class to model it, which contains methods to get the `OracleDynamicParameters`, the `CommandText`, and so forth, and also includes an auto-implemented property **for each parameter**

```
public class DO_SOMETHING {
    ... //code to return parameters, etc
    public string OUT_SUCCESS { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and I have tried all of the following syntax:

```
using (var gridReader = Connection.QueryMultiple(nModel.CommandText(), param: nModel.DynamicParameters(), commandType: nModel.CommandType()))
{
     OUT_SUCCESS = ((OracleDynamicParameters)Model.DynamicParameters()).Get<string>("OUT_SUCCESS"); // 1
     OUT_SUCCESS = gridReader.Read<string>().Single(); //2
     OUT_SUCCESS = gridReader.Read<DO_SOMETHING>().Single().OUT_SUCCESS; //3
}
```

but none of them work:

1. The `AttachedParam` is `null` for the parameter with name `"OUT_SUCCESS"` (although I can see the parameter exists)
2. The `gridReader` reports that the "sequence contains no elements", probably because it has no idea how to read a string out of the response.
3. This one seems the most promising - `InvalidArgumentException`: the `gridReader` advises me that "When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id", but I'm not really sure how this is pertinent to my problem.

By the way, I do know that the procedure is successfully executing because ODP.NET does not produce an exception and I see the resulting rows persisted in the database.

I don't know how to proceed, but I'd really like to use Dapper, as this is the last remaining hurdle to climb. Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: how did you solve the issue number 1? AttachedParam is null.

Comment: I would dearly love to know if you solved this one - I need to call sps that have both Output parameters AND a RefCursor.

Comment: @kpollock I missed your comment but I'll post answer now (prob too late)

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos can you post the solution with `OracleDynamicParameters` ?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is extremely late and may be common knowledge to most everyone but me, but there is a comment in the original message from not too long ago, so I'll describe how I got around the issue of having a cursor out parameter as well as non-cursor out parameters.

Since my example only has one Oracle cursor, I can user the Query method.  The results of the other out parameters are in the parameters themselves and can be retrieved with the Get<> method in the OracleDynamicParameters class.

The other important part for me was to add a size to my out parameters, otherwise they were coming back as null or empty strings.

Below is a sample of the code I'm using.

```
using (IDbConnection db = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
    p.Add("p_first_parameter", someParameter, OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
    p.Add("o_cursr", dbType: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    p.Add("o_sqlerrm", dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 200);
    p.Add("o_sqlcode", dbType: OracleDbType.Varchar2, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 200);

    dynamic csr = db.Query("myStoredProcedure", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList().First();
    string code = p.Get<OracleString>("o_sqlcode").ToString();
    if (code != "0") {
        string errm = p.Get<OracleString>("o_sqlerrm").ToString();
        throw new Exception($"{code} - {errm}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the connection, then read the output parameter.